# Camera Preview showing colorfull snow preview

Tags: android, camera

[image]

The code im using is a lot like APIDemos for Camera, what could cause this to heppen? anyone else encountered this bug?

This is a screen shot from a real device (Samsung S3)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use an emulator or did you ran the sample project into a physical android device? If you're using an emulator - you should set your webcam as your emulated device's  front/back camera.

[image: Edit Android Virtual Device settings]